# Passing cell data (ie cell.textlabel.text and cell.imageView.image) to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView populated with data (text & image). When the user taps on the specific row item, it will segue to a detailViewController which populates the selected row item's text and image into the next view controller.

I am using prepareForSegue instead of didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

the titleForRow:indexPath.row in:indexPath.section and imageForRow:... methods are to populate the title (cell.textLabel.text) and image (cell.imageView.image) for each row item. I did not use a datamodel as this is merely a template to be shown on the detailViewController (UNFDetailLoginTableViewController)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addLoginToDetailLoginTVC"])
{
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    UNFDetailLoginTableViewController *targetVC = (UNFDetailLoginTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.addLoginTableView indexPathForCell:sender];


    targetVC.loginNameTextField.text = [self titleForRow:indexPath.row in:indexPath.section];
    targetVC.detailLoginImage.image = [self imageForRow:indexPath.row in:indexPath.section];

    NSLog (@"%@", [self titleForRow:indexPath.row in:indexPath.section]);
  }
```

}

Upon tapping the specific row , it does segue to the detailLoginTableViewController but the data does not populate. However, the NSLog logs the correct data supposed to be passed to the detailLoginTableViewController. Please help. THank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the properties of the destination viewController are `IBOutlets`, then as they are not set before the destionation view loads, you need to pass the data to intermediate property and then in the viewDidLoad method of your `targetVC` set your outlets.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addLoginToDetailLoginTVC"])
{
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    UNFDetailLoginTableViewController *targetVC = (UNFDetailLoginTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.addLoginTableView indexPathForCell:sender];


    targetVC.text = [self titleForRow:indexPath.row in:indexPath.section];
    targetVC.image = [self imageForRow:indexPath.row in:indexPath.section];

    NSLog (@"%@", [self titleForRow:indexPath.row in:indexPath.section]);
}
```

In your UNFDetailLoginTableViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *text;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image;
```

In your UNFDetailLoginTableViewController.m, in viewDidLoad:

```
self.loginNameTextField.text = self.text;
self.detailLoginImage.image = self.image;
```

Comment: Hi Martin. Yup they are IBOutlets. Could you advice how would you pass the data to an intermediate property. Yes, i have not declared them in the viewDidLoad for the targetVC as I'm not sure how to connect them.

Comment: Sure, try the added code. If that works, you can also move your outlets into m.

Comment: Thanks Martin. But it's still not passing the data. I tried logging NSLog (@"%@", targetVC.text) and it's null.

Comment: I suggest you create a new project based on MasterDetail template. MasterVC passes the `object` in its `prepareForSegue` to DetailVC. The DetailVC sets its outlet in `viewDidLoad` to make sure the information is passed to the outlet when it is finally set. The outlet in that example is also set in the object setter for the case the DetailVC is already loaded and you are just seeing detail of different row. Alternatively, you can use viewWillAppear for both cases. Try that and if you don't succeed, come back and I provide full example with your images and texts.

Comment: I went back to your earlier suggestion per answer and this time in the addLoginViewController , NSLog (@"%@", targetVC.text) returns correctly but in the UNFDetailLoginTableViewController NSLog of self.text / self.image returns (null). Basically the data is correct in the segue just not passed to the UNFDetailLoginTableViewController. Had a look a the MasterDetail template, i tried setting the object self.text = text; under  -(void)setText:(NSString *)text but returns an error EXE_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: I created the sample for you, however xcode is constantly crashing when I try to commit to github. Here is the zipped version via dropbox before xcode starts working again: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w20n84bxvywumna/OutletSettingExample.zip

Comment: Thanks again Martin for your help. I see what your example is doing...it didnt work earlier even i replicated your code in almost exact terms. BUt strangely it worked after i cleaned the project and changed the targetVC.text = cell.textLabel.text; THANK YOU!!!!